# How to change the offsetX and offsetY coordinates from pixels to percentage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am developing a tool where I want the offsetX and offsetY coordinates in percentage(%) format while hovering over to the div element. By default, it is coming in the pixels format.

index.html File:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Events</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="vue-events">
          <h1>Events in VueJS</h1>
          <div id="canvas" v-on:mousemove="updateXY">
            <img src="img/img-1.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;" />
              {{x}}, {{y}}
          </div>
        </div>
       <script src="js/events.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

event.js File:

```
new Vue({
      el: '#vue-events',
      methods:{
        updateXY: function(event){
           this.x = event.offsetX;
           this.y = event.offsetY;
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate this on your self

You get the window width & height and base on this you can calculate the percentage. But keep in mind that the value could be different if you resize your window.

```
   new Vue({
      el: '#vue-events',
      methods:{
        updateXY: function(event){
           this.x = (event.offsetX * 100) / window.innerWidth;
           this.y = (event.offsetY * 100) / window.innerHeight;
        }
      }
    });
```